# Activity crashing the second time it is launched through intent

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, activity-finish

I am designing a simple store/retrieve data android app using firebase.

`Activity1` is a login activity, that goes straight to `Activity2` when a user successfully logs in. There are no problems when logging in the first time, everything is in its proper place. I have a Navigation Drawer in `Activity2` which I use to switch fragments, and in that navigation drawer, users can logout and go back to the login activity. Below is an excerpt from `Activity2` that takes the user back to the login activity

```
            case R.id.nav_logout:
            account_key = "";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
```

When I click the logout button, it takes me to `Activity1` as it should be. Now the problem is when I try to login again, the app just crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.adzu.bfarsystem, PID: 2143
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.add(int, int, int, java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:540)
        at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:193)
        at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:114)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:120)
        at com.adzu.bfarmobile.activities.MainActivity.createSearchView(MainActivity.java:153)
        at com.adzu.bfarmobile.activities.MainActivity$1.dataRetrieved(MainActivity.java:109)
        at com.adzu.bfarmobile.entities.DatabaseReader$3.onChildAdded(DatabaseReader.java:64)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

And here are the lines that triggered the errors:

**LoginActivity.java Lines 95-102**

```
               if (activated) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    newIntent.putExtra("account_key", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                    finish();
                }
```

**MainActivity.java Line 95-127**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
account_key = intent.getStringExtra("account_key");

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("account");
DatabaseReader.readDataByKey(account_key, ref, new OnGetDataListener() {
    @Override
    public void dataRetrieved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Account user = new Account((Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
        fragment1 = new ListFragment();
        fragment1.setUser(user);
        createSearchView();
        showSearchView();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_operatorlist);
        TextView acct_name = findViewById(R.id.acct_name);
        acct_name.setText("Logged in as: " + user.getUsername());
    }

    @Override
    public void dataExists(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {

    }
});
```

**MainActivity.java Line 141-153**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void createSearchView(){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setMenuItem(searchItem);
    expandableLayout = findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
```

**DatabaseReader.java Line 64-89**

```
    public static void readDataByKey(String account_key, DatabaseReference ref, final OnGetDataListener listener) {
        listener.onStart();
        Query query = ref.orderByKey().equalTo(account_key);
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                listener.dataRetrieved(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                listener.onFailure();
            }
        });

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may run into a race condition.
You may have invoked **createSearchView** before the system calls **onCreateOptionsMenu**, so menu is **null**.

Try to have **onCreateOptionsMenu** invoke **createSearchView** after line:

```
this.menu = menu;
```